# Representing 2D array with rects in SVG, and 3d.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

i want to represent a 2d array with rects inside a SVG, and set color to each rect. And after that, and this is where i'm failing (updateTwo), be able to access each rect and change their colors, if needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var data = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 6, 1],
        [0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 7, 0, 1, 1]];

    var SIZE = 20;
    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
            .attr("width", 10 * SIZE)
            .attr("height", 20 * SIZE);
    function update(data) {
        var rectangles = chart
                .selectAll("rect");
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            var rect = rectangles
                    .data(data[j]);

            rect.enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                        return i * SIZE;
                    })
                    .attr("y", (j * SIZE))
                    .attr("width", SIZE - 1)
                    .attr("height", SIZE - 1);
            rect.style("fill", function (d) {
                if (d == 0)
                    return "#000";
                else
                    return colorChoice(d);
            });
        }
    }
    update(data);

    function updateTwo() {
        var gridx = 3;
        var gridy = 3;

        var states = [[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]],
            [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
            [[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
            [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]];

        var rectangles = chart
                .selectAll("rect");

        for (var j = 0; j < states[0].length; j++) {
            var rect = rectangles
                    .data(states[0][j]);

            rect.enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                        return (gridx + i) * SIZE;
                    })
                    .attr("y", (gridy + j) * SIZE)
                    .attr("width", SIZE - 1)
                    .attr("height", SIZE - 1);
            rect.style("fill", function (d) {
                if (d != 0)
                    return "blue";
            });
        }
    }
    updateTwo();

    function colorChoice(colorCode) {
        switch (colorCode)
        {
            case 1:
                return "#FF0000";
            case 2:
                return "#8B4513";
            case 3:
                return "#8A2BE2";
            case 4:
                return "#9ACD32";
            case 5:
                return "#DC143C";
            case 6:
                return "#FF8C00";
            case 7:
                return "#556B2F";
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the output, i see only 2 rects turning blue, in position (0,0), and (0,1), which is wrong. The desired outcome would be getting a shape of "L" in blue.

Comment: All of them are actually coordinates, meaning it's a 10*20 grid.

Comment: The value of each grid represents its color.

Comment: If the value of an (x, y) is zero, that means the grid is "off", and i set it to background color. If the value is higher than zero, then it represents a color, which's decided in my colorChoice function. The position is decided by x and y indexes.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED USING JSON.